# Change and use pre-trained model architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using Tensoflow object detection API for detection of objects.Currently, I am using MobileNet pre-trained model. Now I need to evaluate pre-trained model results under different forms of the model.To do that I need to do some slit changes to the model architecture.

Is it possible?. If then How to do that?.